# Recurrent event survival model set-up

Tags: data-transformation, survival

I'm trying to model customer reorders using a survival model using R's `survival` package and am having a hard time figuring out if I'm setting up the data correctly and if I'm running the analysis correctly.

My raw data is simply a data frame with customer ids, an order date and the value of the order (unimportant for now), like so:

```
> orders
# A tibble: 666,589 x 3
   cust_code order_date order_value
       <chr>     <date>       <dbl>
1     100006 2016-01-12        14.9
2     100006 2016-03-04        15.3
3     100008 2016-01-09        23.6
4     100008 2016-02-07        23.6
5     100008 2016-02-21        29.8
6     100008 2016-04-17        18.8
7     100008 2016-04-17        14.9
8     100008 2016-06-07        20.9
9     100008 2016-07-04        16.9
10    100009 2016-01-12        15.8
# ... with 666,579 more rows
```

This data I'm transforming so that I can then feed it into `Surv()`:

```
> orders %>%
+   arrange(cust_code, order_date) %>%
+   group_by(cust_code) %>%
+   mutate(first_order_date = min(order_date)) %>%
+   mutate(days_since_first_order = as.numeric(order_date - first_order_date)) %>%
+   mutate(days_last_order = lag(days_since_first_order)) -> edited_orders
> edited_orders
Source: local data frame [666,589 x 6]
Groups: cust_code [209,805]

   cust_code order_date order_value first_order_date days_since_first_order days_last_order
       <chr>     <date>       <dbl>           <date>                  <dbl>           <dbl>
1     100006 2016-01-12        14.9       2016-01-12                      0              NA
2     100006 2016-03-04        15.3       2016-01-12                     52               0
3     100008 2016-01-09        23.6       2016-01-09                      0              NA
4     100008 2016-02-07        23.6       2016-01-09                     29               0
5     100008 2016-02-21        29.8       2016-01-09                     43              29
6     100008 2016-04-17        18.8       2016-01-09                     99              43
7     100008 2016-04-17        14.9       2016-01-09                     99              99
8     100008 2016-06-07        20.9       2016-01-09                    150              99
9     100008 2016-07-04        16.9       2016-01-09                    177             150
10    100009 2016-01-12        15.8       2016-01-12                      0              NA
# ... with 666,579 more rows

> count_data <- Surv(time=edited_orders$days_last_order,
+                    time2=edited_orders$days_since_first_order,
+                    event=rep(TRUE, nrow(edited_orders)),
+                    origin=0,
+                    type='counting')
```

If I now look at the output of `plot(survfit(count_data ~ 1, data=edited_orders))`, the hazard function pretty quickly goes to zero:

[image: hazard function]

I assume that this is because the curve is the hazard function conditional on the unit eventually dying (re-ordering). But this doesn't seem to take into account that most units don't, in fact, die. Do I need to augment the dataset with observations that have `event=FALSE` from the date of their last purchase until the final day available in the dataset? Or am I simply thinking about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

In the current model what you are doing, you are defining time 0 as *time of the first purchase*, then assuming a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda(t)$. The "survival" function at time $t$ is then 
$$
\exp\left(\int_0^t \lambda(s) ds\right)
$$
The problem is that this is can not be interpreted as a survival function in the classical sense. It reflects in fact the probability of no events before time $t$, so that is what the curve above shows.

If you are more interested in time between events (time to *next* purchase), then you should use the so-called gap-time formulation, where you feed the survival function only with a `tstop` value equal to the gap between events.

Comment: What I'm primarily interested in is the reorder-probability and I have a secondary interest in the time to next purchase, which is why I had assumed a model for recurrent events was the most appropriate in this context.